# Font Drawable for paid font

Tags: android, custom-font, android-fonts

I was using Montserrat font for my app previously following is font.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
    app:fontProviderQuery="Montserrat"
    app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

Now I want to use paid font which I bought recently. I want to know how can I create font drawable for paid font.

Comment: Are you saying you have a `.ttf` or `.otf` font file you paid for? Where is this paid font from?

Comment: I want to know if it can be done without .ttf or .otf file as done for Montserrat custom font

Comment: Where is your paid font from?

Comment: https://www.myfonts.com/

Comment: What font file / access system / whatever do you currently have? How do you access it? You've got to provide some actual information for someone to be able to help you!

Comment: In the snippet above, you're using Google Fonts from Google Play Services as the font provider. You can't do that for your custom font unless you have a font provider application (for Android) on that as well.